# What is the best database schema to connect "students" and "schools"

Tags: database, database-relations

Using this simplified example; what approach do you think is better and why?

Edit: The relation must be 1 to 1. A student only exists in one school.

```
Option1

**Table Schools:**
id int primary key;
name string;
**Table students:**
id int primary key;
name string;
idSchool int;

Option2

**Table Schools:**
id int primary key;
name string;
**Table Students:**
id int primary key;
name string;
**Table SchoolsStudents**
idSchool int;
idStudent int;
idSchool, idStudent as primary key;
```

Comment: *The relation must be 1 to 1. A student only exists in one school.*  Thse two statements are **not** equivalent.  If the relationship between Students and Schools is "1 to 1", then all Students attend at most one School *and all Schools have at most one Student*.  Is that really what you intend?  Please clarify.

Answer (score 3):

Option1 one makes sense if a student can only attend one school. Option2 is necessary if a student can attend multiple schools.